# Negative $q$-binomial series: reference request

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, qa.quantum-algebra

There seems to be a result for formal series (I hope this is right) for all integer $r\ge 0$
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0} (-x)^n\ {{n+r}\choose{r}}_{q} = (1+x)^{-1}(1+qx)^{-1}\dots
(1+q^{r}x)^{-1}
$$
where the $q$-binomial coefficients are written in terms of the $q$ integers
$[t]=1+q+\dots+ q^{t-1}$. This is a fairly direct analogue of the classical negative binomial theorem (careful choice of $x$ will make it convergent).

I was hoping that someone could give a reference for where to find this - it does not seem to be trivial to prove. Apologies for not knowing what is likely a very standard reference!

Comment: or Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, a formula between (1.86) and (1.87) on p.74

Comment: Many thanks for that! It is very useful.